# Calculating Confidence Interval

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, mean

How would one go solving for this?

***You are told that a 95% CI for expected lead content when traffic flow is 15, based on a sample of n = 12 observations, is (468.1, 591.7). Calculate a CI with confidence level 99% for expected lead content when traffic flow is 15. (Round your answers to one decimal place.)***

Thanks

Comment: I added the `self-study` tag because this is a homework question. Also, you should show us what you've tried so far to attempt to answer the question.

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @JDAWG92, but we treat them differently. Please tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you are stuck, & we'll try to provide hints to get you unstuck. Please edit your question to add this information. To better understand the process, you should read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `[self-study]` tag.

Answer (score 1):

A $c$% confidence interval for data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is defined as
$$ (\bar{x} - q_c\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}, \bar{x} + q_c\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}})$$
where

- $n$ is the number of samples,
- $s$ is the sample standard deviation, and
- $q_c$ is the appropriate quantile, the $(100-(100-c)/2)$th percentile of an appropriate distribution (usually the normal or t distribution, see below). In the case of $c=95\%$, $q_c$ is the $100-(5/2)=97.5$th percentile.

Assuming your data is normally distributed, you can use the t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom for the quantiles: you can look the quantiles up in tables or use a software package.

Defining the standard error as $\sigma_M=s/\sqrt{n}$, the confidence interval can be written
$$ \;(\bar{x} - q_c\sigma_M, \bar{x} + q_c\sigma_M)$$

For further background search for "t confidence intervals". [Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/statistics-inferential/hypothesis-testing/v/t-statistic-confidence-interval) is good and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Confidence_intervals) is worth a look too.

That's the theory. To solve your problem what you need to do is:

1. Figure out what $q_c$ is for the given confidence interval with $c=95\%$ and $n=12$, looking up using the appropriate t distribution.
2. Given the width of the confidence interval, and the distance either side of the mean to the boundaries, solve for $\sigma_M$ and $\bar{x}$.
3. Figure out what $q_c$ is for the required confidence interval with $c=99\%$ in a similar way to what you did in step 1.
4. Use your new $q_c$ and $\sigma_M$, $\bar{x}$ to calculate the new confidence interval.